# Counting syllables

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm looking to assign some different readability scores to text in R such as the Flesh Kincaid.

Does anyone know of a way to segment words into syllables using R?  I don't necessarily need the syllable segments themselves but a count.

so for instance:

```
x <- c('dog', 'cat', 'pony', 'cracker', 'shoe', 'Popsicle')
```

would yield:
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3

Each number corresponding the the number of syllables in the word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some tools for NLP are available here:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html

The task is non-trivial though.  More hints (including an algorithm you could implement) here:

[Detecting syllables in a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405161/detecting-syllables-in-a-word)

Answer (score 12):

[qdap version 1.1.0](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/qdap-1-1-0-released-on-cran/) does this task:

```
library(qdap)
x <- c('dog', 'cat', 'pony', 'cracker', 'shoe', 'Popsicle')
syllable_sum(x)

## [1] 1 1 2 2 1 3
```

Answer (score 8):

gsk3 is correct:  if you want a **correct solution**, it is **non-trivial**.

For example, you have to watch out for strange things like silent e at the end of a word (eg *pane*), or know when it's not silent, as in *finale*.

However, if you just want a **quick-and-dirty approximation**,  this will do it:

```
> nchar( gsub( "[^X]", "", gsub( "[aeiouy]+", "X", tolower( x ))))
[1] 1 1 2 2 1 3
```

To understand how the parts work, just strip away the function calls from the outside in, starting with `nchar` and then `gsub`, etc...  ...until the expression makes sense to you.

But my guess is, considering a fight between R's power vs the profusion of exceptions in the English language, you could get a decent answer (maybe 99% right?) parsing through normal text, without a lot of work - heck, the simple parser above may get 90%+ right.  With a little more work, you could deal with silent e's if you like.

It all depends on your application - whether this is *good enough* or you need something more accurate.

Comment: ty - gotta love regular-expressions 8^)

Comment: A more efficient & simpler version of the same approximation would be something like `sapply(gregexpr("[aeiouy]+", x, ignore.case=TRUE), length)`.

Comment: @kfmfe04 I have actually used your base and added some mods and am at about a 95% accuracy rate.  I'm searching now for a dictionary to run before the algorith (as was the suggestion in the link provided gsk3).  If I could mark both answers correct I would but alas can not.  Thank you for your thoughtful response.

Answer (score 5):

The [koRpus](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/koRpus/index.html) package will help you out immensley, but it's a little difficult to work with.

```
stopifnot(require(koRpus))
tokens <- tokenize(text, format="obj", lang='en')
flesch.kincaid(tokens)
```

Comment: I now have a function to count syllables very accurately and to do flesch.kincaid.  I plan on releasing it some time this summer.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker That's awesome! Post a comment back here when it's out.  How fast is your function?

Comment: I did benchmarking at the time (got a lot of help using hash tables from talkstats.com people) but can't remember off hand.  let's just say that it's as fast as on line syllable counters and more accurate.  I use a combined dictionary/algorithm approach.  The hash table makes it fly.

Comment: On github: `# install.packages("devtools");
library(devtools);
install_github("qdap", "trinker")`