# Python or R readability

Tags: python, r, text, readability

Are there any packages in Python or R that can take text and give back its readability?  For example, kids are said to read at a certain grade level.  I want to be able to get a grade level (or analogous readability measure) for a given text.

Comment: I don't do this stuff but could the qdap package in R offer what you want? Possibly this: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qdap/docs/automated_readability_index

Comment: Maybe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553240/counting-syllables

Answer (score 3):

An implementation of the [Flesch-Kincaid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch%E2%80%93Kincaid_readability_tests) readability statistic is in here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/koRpus/koRpus.pdf

Comment: +1, and I really don't understand the downvote, since it's a "*A set of tools to analyze texts. Includes, amongst others,functions for automatic language
detection, hyphenation, several indices of
lexical diversity and
**readability***"

Comment: it is a link-only answer, but on the other hand that's what the question asked for (and why it was closed ...)