# How to break a sentence into syllables in Java

Tags: java, string, words

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting syllables in a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405161/detecting-syllables-in-a-word)

Assume the input string is "saya sedang makan nasi goreng"
I want to break it into syllables: 
"sa", "ya", "se", "dang", "ma", "kan", "na", "si", "go", "reng"

How can I do it in Java? can somebody help me?

Comment: I think this is a problem of defining the formal rules for what constitutes a syllable in Indonesian, rather than a programming problem. Once you have defined the formal rules, the programming should be *trivial*.

Comment: A good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405161/detecting-syllables-in-a-word

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann The program *may* be trivial, but the dictionary that it needs might be rather large :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - If you read the linked Q/A's, syllable splitting in English done by applying a fixed set rules and using a *small* dictionary of words that rules don't work for.  I'd expect the rule set / dictionary to be smaller for Indonesian because the spelling / pronunciation are more consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an easy thing to do. But, if you still want to do it, I think your best bet is to search for a dictionary database (which gives you syllable breakdown for every word, though this is hard to find), download it and write a program to query the database and fetch the syllable breakup.

Answer (score 1):

Without voice input, you need a 'Syllable Dictionary' to do that.

EDIT: [It's been discussed on this site already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405161/detecting-syllables-in-a-word).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naive solution:

```java
String input = "saya sedang makan nasi goreng";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^aeiou]?[AEIOUaeiou](ng|n)?").matcher(input);
int s = 0;
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(input.substring(s, m.end()).trim());
  s = m.end();
}
```

**Edit:**
@Stephen C is right. Here's a proper solution based on syllable formation rules of the Indonesian language (from [source](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=UogWkiAbiYQC&lpg=PA1&ots=3ix4odXdTc&dq=indonesian%20syllables&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q=indonesian%20syllables&f=false))

> In Indonesian a syllable consists of a vowel plus the immediately
>   precending consonant. It also includes anyh following consonant that
>   does not immediately precede the next vowel.

Note that *ng* counts as a single consonant.

```java
String input = "SAYA sedang makan nasi goreng garam asal saat air ia bentuk";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^aeiou]?[aeiou]((ng|[^aeiou])(?![aeiou]))?",
              Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(input);
int s = 0;
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(input.substring(s, m.end()).trim());
  s = m.end();
}
```

Please note that (also mentioned in the source above) syllables as they are pronounced in speech may be slightly different, e.g. in-speech: *ma-kan-an*, program output: *ma-ka-nan*.

**Edit 2:**
OK. Further studying revealed that I have missed out the *ny*, *sy* and *kh* consonants. Also fixed couple of other problems. Here's the updated regular expression:

```java
"(ng|ny|sy|kh|[^aeiou])?[aeiou]((ng|ny|sy|kh|([^aeiou](?![gyh]))(?![aeiou])))?"
```

Comment: a naive solution to a problem like this is probably not a solution at all.

Comment: My bad. See the update for a better attempt:)