# Database with syllable counts

Tags: nlp, nltk, linguistics

Is there a database somewhere with files that contain words tagged by syllable count? I'm looking to implement a haiku generator for fun.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096228/counting-syllables-in-a-word

Comment: i would like such a library too =)

Comment: See my answer for what I ended up using. For part of speech, I cross-referenced the Brown Corpus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Moby Corpus](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/3204) provides a fairly large source of hyphenated words.