# Split word into syllables

Tags: javascript

How to split the syllables in a word using JavaScript. Is there any API for that? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405161/detecting-syllables-in-a-word

Comment: This is a very cool idea! Great question! You may also want to research text-mining and language semantics

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel: This question has been asked numerous times on SO.

Comment: @Ivan : I have not seen this asked referring specifically to Javascript - I apologize if it has been. Natto only has 13 Rep and clearly doesn't know to accept. I may be a newbie to SO and not to web dev., but he might be new, so I'm going to cut him a break. He asked a cool question and I think it deserves some good discussion and rep. We all had to start somewhere, right. As much as I wish that I was cool enough to go around downgrading people's questions because they were asked years and years ago (especially when people yell at you for commenting on old posts) unfortunately I'm not.

Comment: @Ivan: So tell him, nicely, that it is standard courtesy and practice to demonstrate that you have done some research, even if you didn't find any good resources. If he had 100 Rep I would completely agree with you, but clearly he is still new to the system. I think starting him off with a polite suggestion and a bit of a boost is much more effective than just saying nothing, downgrading his question, and hoping he just happens to figure out on his own what he did wrong, when no-one is giving him feedback.

Comment: @Ivan: and as a side-note, I'm the one who upgraded your original comment - not because it was particularly helpful, but because you still took to time to answer even though he didn't know how to ask

Answer (score 1):

Now, back to being constructive, what I suggest is that you find a couple online dictionary sites and look at their APIs (I know dictionary.com has a free API) and see if you can use it to access just the word split into syllables from a lookup.

Unfortunately, from what I have read, it looks like you would really need a dictionary of words split already to check against and there aren't any standalone versions out there.

Be the first and post it somewhere! :)