# Detect Syllables in a Word

Tags: java, nlp, detection

I want to detect syllables in a user-inputted word. Not how many syllables there are, but actually finding the letters that make up each syllable.

I've tried things like getting all the combinations of letters that make up syllables, (VCV, CVV, etc.) and then detecting if the word contains those letters in that pattern, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Because of particularities of each language, I don't think that there is a programmatic way to detect syllabes. One possible way would be to have a list of all words and corresponding syllabes in a file. When the user inputs a word, find the correct entry and display the corresponding syllabes.

Comment: Even in a single language, identical letter sequences can be different words (and thus pronounced differently) depending on their grammatical use, and dialects can change how many pronounced syllables even a single word contains.

Comment: what you need to do, is check how looks structure of syllables in your language, get those rules and apply them, but if you want this to bi multilingual, you need to consider rules in each language seperatly

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405161/detecting-syllables-in-a-word