# Word frequency corpus for natural language processing

Tags: nlp, corpus

I have a open source dictionary / thesaurus and I want to find out the following about each words in the dictionary / thesaurus:

1. The frequency of the word and its synonyms used in any available open corpus. I could find some open corpus like on the [Stanford NLP page](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/links/statnlp.html) but none for word frequency corpus. Is there any open source word frequency corpus already available? If no, I am looking for some pointers to build one.
2. Is there any algorithm / heuristic that classify words into different difficulty levels (eg. very hard, difficult, medium, easy etc) ? Although subjective, but may be the rarity/ frequency of use, ambiguity of meaning i.e. usage in different sense, difficulty of spelling, no of letters in the word etc can be used to classify them. I am looking for any open source package that I can use to find these features especially the word frequency and build a corpus that classify words with difficulty levels.

Comment: Here's one: http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/TweetNLP/cluster_viewer.html It has frequencies for each word in each cluster.

Comment: First question is a request for a resource, which is off-topic.  The second question is rather broad.

Answer (score 1):

1) The British National Corpus (BNC) is not open source, but you can find frequency lists here: http://www.kilgarriff.co.uk/bnc-readme.html

2) I don't know whether such package exists. It looks like a supervised machine learning task to me. Just to give you a couple of ideas: you could use the following features:
- syllable count (see for example [Detecting syllables in a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405161/detecting-syllables-in-a-word))
- lemmata count: more entries indicate ambiguity
- PoS candidate count (probably weaker than lemmata count)
An easy-to-use annotation and machine learning environment can be found here (Gate): https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch19.html#x24-46100019.2