# Counting to a million in Python - Theory

Tags: math, theory, mathematical-optimization

I'm learning Python and came across a question that went something like "How long would it take to count to 1,000,000 out loud?"  The only parameter it gave was, "you count, on average, 1 digit per second."  I did that problem, which wasn't very difficult.  Then I started thinking about counting aloud, annunciating each numeral.  That parameter seems off to me, and indeed the answer Google gives to the question alone "how long to count to a million" suggests it's off.  Given that each number in the sequence takes progressively longer (an exponential increase??), there must be a better way.

Any ideas or general guidance would be of assistance.  Would sampling various people's "counting rates" at various intervals work?  Would programming the # of syllables work?  I am really curious, and have looked all over SO and Google for solutions that don't revolve around that seemingly inaccurate "average time".

Thanks, and sorry if this isn't on topic or in the appropriate place. I'm a long time lurker, but new to posting, so let me know if you need more info or anything.  Thanks!

Comment: I think your intuition is a good strategy. Help along that path: [integer to word](https://www.exchangecore.com/blog/convert-number-words-c-sharp-console-application/) and [syllables per word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405161/detecting-syllables-in-a-word).

Comment: You should try a lot of things, that's clear. But how to measure what is better and which went worse? I think you could verify your every thesis using IVONA text to speach engine. http://www.ivona.com/ (and probably you would be able to automate such tests in python)

Comment: "Given that each number in the sequence takes progressively longer..." If I understand you, I think this assumption is wrong. 9999 -> 10000 is one counterexample.

Comment: @Anonymous thanks for the link.  I'm almost done building a 'syllable counting app' in Python, IVONA should come in handy to check my work with!

Comment: @BilltheLizard you're right now that I think of it.  The way our numerals get pronounced are a lot more nuanced than I had considered, so maybe the average given is closer than I thought.  Thanks!

Comment: I would think that the worst-case time for pronouncing an n-digit numbers grows closer to something like log(n) than exponential. Consider the number of syllables (which is fairly linearly related to time taken to pronounce) in 777,777 versus 77,777.

Answer (score 3):

Let us suppose for the sake of simplicity that you don't say 1502 as "fifteen hundred and two", but as "thousand five hundred and two". Then we can hierarchically break it down.

And let's ignore the fact whether you say "and" or not ([though apparently it is more said than not](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37958/how-do-you-correctly-say-large-numbers)) for now. I will use this reference (and British English, because I like it more and it's more consistent : http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=15&langid=6) for how to pronounce numbers.

In fact, to formally describe this, let `t` be a function of a set of numbers, that tells you how much time it takes to pronounce every number in that set. Then your question is how to compute `t([1..1000000])`, and we will use `M=t([1..999])`

### Triplet time in function of previous one

> To read a large number we start at the left and read the three-digit groups. The group at the left, of course, may have only one or two digits.

Thus for every number `x` of thousands you will say `x thousand y` where `y` will describe all the numbers from 1 to 999.

Thus the time you spend in the `x thousand ...` is `1000 t({1000x}) + M`, as detailed here after :

[image: detail of t(1000x)]

Note that this formula is generalizable to numbers below 1000, by simply defining `t({0}) = 0`.

Now the time to say "x thousand" is, per our hypothesis, equal to the time to say "x" plus the time to say "thousand" (when x > 0). Thus your answer is :

[image: sum to a million]

Where [image: tau(thousand)] is the time it takes to say the word thousand. This supposes you say 1000 as "one thousand". You may want to remove `1000 tau("one")` if you would only say "thousand".

How ever I stick with the reference :

> The numbers 100-199 begin with one hundred... or a hundred...

You can in exactly the same way express the time it takes to count to a billion from [image: tau(million)] and the number above, and so on for all the greater powers of 10<sup>3</sup>, i.e. 
[image: generalization]

### Taking into account the "and"

There is a small correction to be done. Let us suppose that `M` is the time it takes to pronounce numbers from 1 to 999 **when they are preceded by at least a non-0 group of numbers, including initial "and"s**.

Our reference (well, the wordreference post I linked) says the following :

> What do we say to join the groups?
>   Normally, we don’t use any joining word.
>   The exception is the last group.
>   If the last group after the thousands is 1-99 it is joined with and.

Thus our correction applies only to the numbers between 0 and 999 (where there is no non-zero group preceding) :

[image: time from 1 to 999]

### Getting M

Or rather, let's get t([1..999]) since it's more natural and we know how it is related to M.

Let `C = t([1..99])`, `X = t([1..9])`.

Between 1 and 999 we have all the numbers from [1..99] and all the 9 exact hundreds where you don't say "and", that is 108 occurences. There are 900 numbers prefixed with a hundreds number.

Thus [image: from 1 to 999]

C is probably hard to break down, so I'm not going to try.

### Final result

The corrected formula is :
[image: count to 1 billion as f(M)]

And as a function of C and X :
[image: count to 1 billion as f(C,X)]

Note that your measures of tau(word), C, and X need to be very precise if you plan on doing this multiplication and having any kind of correct order of magnitude.

Conclusion : Brits end up saying "and" a whole lot. The nice thing about the last formulation is that you can remove all the "and"s if you decide you actually don't want to pronounce them.

Comment: just logged in to give you a very deserved +1