# Filter words from a file based on their number of syllables

Tags: python, nltk

I need to identify complex words from a .txt file.
I am trying to use nltk but no such module exist.
Complex words are words in the text that contains more than two syllables.

Comment: Have you done anything to try to identify complex words? Do you have an example TXT file or sample code? What constitutes a complex word?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by "complex words"? Please see [ask]; the more clear and complete your question is the more likely you'll get a helpful response.

Comment: Can you post a sample of this text file? I'm not sure what you mean by "complex words".

Comment: See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/405179/9518258). Your best bet is to either implement the algorithm described in the disseration linked to there, or to use a dictionary which includes this kind of metadata.

Comment: A better question `What is a "complex word"`? See https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.09132 =)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Pyphen](http://pyphen.org/). This module has a `Pyphen` class used for hyphenation. One of its methods, `positions()`, returns the number of places in a word where it can be split:

```
>>> from pyphen import Pyphen
>>> p = Pyphen(lang='en_US')
>>> p.positions('exclamation')
[2, 5, 7]
```

If the word "exclamation" can be split in three places, it has four syllables, so you just need to filter all words with more than one split place.

. . .

But I noted you tagged it as an [t:nltk] question. I'm not experienced with NLTK myself but [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4103234/287976) suggested by @Jules has a nice suggestion in this aspect: to use the `cmudict` module. It gives you a list of pronunciations of a word in American English:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import cmudict
>>> d = cmudict.dict()
>>> pronounciations = d['exasperation']
>>> pronounciations
[['EH2', 'K', 'S', 'AE2', 'S', 'P', 'ER0', 'EY1', 'SH', 'AH0', 'N']]
```

Luckily, our fist word has only one pronounciation. It is represented as a list of strings, each one representing a phoneme:

```
>>> phonemes = pronounciations[0]
>>> phonemes
['EH2', 'K', 'S', 'AE2', 'S', 'P', 'ER0', 'EY1', 'SH', 'AH0', 'N']
```

Note that [vowel phonemes have a number at the end, indicating stress](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/cmudict.html):

> Vowels are marked for stress (1=primary, 2=secondary, 0=no stress).  E.g.: NATURAL 1 N AE1 CH ER0 AH0 L

So, we just need to count the number of phonemes with digits at the end:

```
>>> vowels = [ph for ph in phonemes if ph[-1].isdigit()]
>>> vowels
['EH2', 'AE2', 'ER0', 'EY1', 'AH0']
>>> len(vowels)
5
```

. . .

Not sure which is the best option but I guess you can work your problem out from here.