# How to get all the syllables of a word in Python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, medical

I am looking to split the word into its syllables. I am trying to build a speech-to-text system but focused on transcribing medical terms.

Consider a doctor/pharmacist who instead of typing out the medicine dosage would just speak into the microphone and a digital prescription would be generated automatically.
I want to avoid ML/DL based approaches since I wanted the system to work in real-time. Therefore I wanted to tackle this problem via a dictionary-based approach. I have **scraped** the `rxlist.com` to get all the possible medicine names.
Currently, I am using the webspeech API (https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html). This works well but often messes up the medicine names.

1. Panadol twice a day for three days would become panel twice a day for three days

It works sometimes (super unstable). Also, it is important to consider that panadol is a relatively simple *term*. Consider Vicodin (changed to why couldn't), Abacavir Sulfate, etc.

Here is the approach I thought could perhaps work.

1. Maintain a dictionary of all medicines.
2. Once the detections are there (I append all the detections instead of just using the last output), compare the string distance from each medicine (could be huge, so sorting is important here) and replace the word with minimum error.
3. If nothing matches (maintain a threshold of error in step 2), check the syllables of prediction and that of medicine name and replace the one with the lowest error.

So I now have the list, I was hoping if I could find a library/dictionary API which could give me the syllables of medicine names. Typing `How to pronounce vicodin` on Google gets the Learn to Pronounce panel which has: vai·kuh·dn. I would want something similar, now I could **scrape** it off of Google, but I don't get the results for all the medicine names.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting syllables in a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405161/detecting-syllables-in-a-word)

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is off-topic on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library called pyphen. It's pretty easy to use. To install it run the following command in your terminal:

```
pip install pyphen
```

After this, find out the syllables in a string:

```
import pyphen
a = pyphen.Pyphen(lang='en')
print(a.inserted('vicodin'))
```

I hope you find this useful