# How to separate Phonetic, Word Break and Word Join keywords from list of keywords using python?

Tags: python, spell-checking, word-break, phonetics

I want to separate phonetic, word break and word join keywords from a list of keywords using Python. Example:

Input List:

```
rice1kg
oil
cooking oil
oliv oil
flour5kg
buther
baking povder
Leg umes
```

Expected Output:

```
rice 1kg - word break
olive oil - phonetic
flour 5kg - word break
butter - phonetic
baking powder - phonetic
legumes - word join
```

Comment: Could you define the difference between a word break and phonetic keyword? Does word break always refer to a split on a number (`rice5kg -> rice 5 kg`)? If not, would `oliveoil` count as a word break?

Comment: Also are you working with a finite set of possible words (I'd assume it's all ingredients and measurements if that is the case) or does your script need to accommodate all possible words and combinations? İf you could give a more full explanation of your problem it would help a lot in answering.

Comment: Hi @RufusBarnes word break is basically two different words combined in one for example: cookingoil is a word-break query and cooking oil is a correct spell query. It is not necessary to split on a number. and Phonetic spell keywords are where we write spellings based on human pronunciation for example: nudles which is a phonetic query and the correct word is noodles.

Comment: and the script needs to be accommodate all possible words and combinations. and one more point is, that I don't want to correct the words just want to separate them based on phonetic, word-break.

Comment: Could I ask what the source of this problem is? Has it been assigned to you as part of a course, your job, or is it personal? Just because to me this seems like an incredibly complicated problem that you might need to break down into smaller tasks before approaching.

Comment: You could start by importing a module (like this https://pypi.org/project/english-words/) as your reference for English words. Then you need to work on a way to logically define what a word break, phonetic and word join keyword actually is. For word join for example, you could check if `keyword.replace(' ', '') in english_words`. If it is, then the keyword is an English word split by a space.

Comment: For me I would say: `word join`: an English word with spaces inserted in the middle   /   `word break`: multiple English words not separated by spaces   /   `phonetic`: a much more difficult problem. English words spelled incorrectly that would be pronounced similarly. Classifying phonetic words could in my opinion be a project by itself.

Comment: You might have some success first splitting the keyword into syllables. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405161/detecting-syllables-in-a-word) might help with that.

Comment: You also have the problem that measurements are not technically English words, but in your code are treated as such. For example, `1kg` is correct grammatically but is not found in a dictionary so would require additional logic.

Comment: I'd be inclinded to break it into two problems: 1) segmentation issues, this is basically the examples with ingredient and measure without space between, and could be handled by regex; 2) I'd be inclined to treat all the others as misspellings, and hook in a spell checking module. Honestly, there will be no approach that will be 100% foolproof, especially with English

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complicated problem without a definite answer. In it's simplest form it essentially breaks down into categorising strings into three categories:

- **Word Join** - An **English** word split into two parts separated by a space character. ie. `wo rd`
- **Word Break** - Two **English** words that should be separated by a space character. ie. `wordbreak`
- **Phonetic** - One or more english words spelled incorrectly, but that would be pronounced the same as their correctly spelled counterparts. ie. `toylet`

There are a large number of problems that would need to be solved to complete this categorisation. I'll list some of them below:

1. How would you categorise the string `pullover`. Is that correctly spelled, ie. `pullover: a knitted garment`, or a word break, ie. `pull over`? This is just an example, but there are a lot of cases where a string could be placed logically into multiple categories.
2. How are you defining a correctly spelled word? Is it in the English dictionary? If so, what about measurements, like `200mm`, `5kg`, `20"`, etc.
3. How are you defining phonetic similarity?  One approach would be to split each word into syllables, and then translate each syllable into the international phonetic alphabet, which is itself a difficult task and still has its own problems. Is the sound `oo` pronounced as it is in the word `food`, or the word `good`? The English language is stitched together from many sources, with borrowed words and linguistic roots in multiple places, so it doesn't follow a set of fixed rules when pronouncing words. This, in my opinion, is what makes this task so difficult.

I can't offer solutions to these problems, but knowing what challenges you'll face when you approach this task is a good way to start.

Comment: I'd also like to comment that some of the phonetic examples you gave don't make sense. For example, `povder` would not be pronounced the same as `powder` in English.